# search and retrieve data from xml using extjs

Tags: html, xml, extjs

This is XML file named "students.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Students>
    <Student>
    <Name>Mahesh A</Name>
    <College>NITW</College>
    <Stream>ECE</Stream>
    <Status>Selected</Status>
    </Student>
    <Student>
    <Name>Vikram M</Name>
    <College>IIMA</College>
    <Stream>CS</Stream>
    <Status>Not Selected</Status>
    </Student>
    <Student>
    <Name>Naresh A</Name>
    <College>IITM</College>
    <Stream>EEE</Stream>
    <Status>Not Selected</Status>
    </Student>
    <Student>
    <Name>Prashanth P</Name>
    <College>NITW</College>
    <Stream>EEE</Stream>
    <Status>Selected</Status>
    </Student>
    <Student>
    <Name>Rashi A</Name>
    <College>MIIM</College>
    <Stream>ECE</Stream>
    <Status>Selected</Status>
    </Student>
    <Student>
    <Name>Vikranth M</Name>
    <College>DBIT</College>
    <Stream>IT</Stream>
    <Status>Selected</Status>
    </Student>
    <Student>
    <Name>Pavan D</Name>
    <College>NIIT</College>
    <Stream>IT</Stream>
    <Status>Not Selected</Status>
    </Student>
    <Student>
    <Name>Vishwanath A</Name>
    <College>IIMA</College>
    <Stream>ECE</Stream>
    <Status>Selected</Status>
    </Student>
    <Student>
    <Name>Steyn P</Name>
    <College>NIIT</College>
    <Stream>ECE</Stream>
    <Status>Selected</Status>
    </Student>
    </Students>
```

I want to create a search page in html which allows users to enter name and retrieve the data corresponding to that name in "students.xml" file using EXT JS

For example If i enter Mahesh A in search box it should retrive all his data from the "students.xml" document using EXT JS..
Please help me..

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this in `ExtJS`.
[Check out this fiddle I made for the full source.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/33d)

Essentially, you'll need to load the `xml` into a `store` and then you can `filter` the `store` to show the desired matching results.

In my example I'm filtering by the `Name`, you can edit this to filter by anything in the data really.

To load the xml file to a `store`:

```
Ext.define('Student', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                reader: 'xml'
            },
            fields: ['Name', 'College', 'Stream', 'Status']
        });

        // create the Data Store
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'Student',
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                // load using HTTP
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data.xml',
                // the return will be XML, so lets set up a reader
                reader: {
                    type: 'xml',
                    root: 'Students',
                    record: 'Student'
                }
            }
        });
```

Create a `grid` with the corresponding `fields` from the xml file

Then, create a `panel` with the search fields and handlers (although you could technically do this in the `tbar` of the grid) and add the `grid` to it

```
var resultsGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
            store:store,
            columns:[
                {text:'Name',dataIndex:'Name'},
                {text:'College',dataIndex:'College'},
                {text:'Stream',dataIndex:'Stream'},
                {text:'Status',dataIndex:'Status'}
            ]
        })

        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
            renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
            title:'Search',
            tbar:[{
                xtype:'textfield',
                fieldLabel:'Name',
                emptyText:'Search Here',
                itemId:'searchFld'
            },{
                xtype:'button',
                text:'Search',
                handler:function(btn){
                    var searchValue = btn.up('form').down('#searchFld').getValue();
                    if(searchValue==''){
                        store.clearFilter();
                    }
                    else{
                        store.filterBy(function(record,id){
                            return record.get('Name')==searchValue;
                        })
                    }
                }
            }],
            items:[resultsGrid]
        });
```

For some really great examples just check out [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/grid/xml-grid.html)