# adding html form data to an existing xml file using Java Script

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I want to save data from an HTML form to an XML file using Java Script
for example my form has two fields named  "name" "rollnum"...now the data entered in these fields should be saved in an xml file as

```
<name>xx</name> 
<rollnum>xxxx</rollnum>
```

Please help me...

Comment: You can't do that with client side `Javascript`. You'll need to do it server side.

Comment: JavaScript running in a browser? JavaScript running on the server (e.g. via node.js)? XML file where? On a server? On a local file system? What problem are you having? Reading the XML file? Manipulating the data? Converting the data back to XML? Storing it?

Comment: This seems to be [a duplicate of your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439053/search-and-retrieve-data-from-xml-using-extjs) … but with less information about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is imposible with only javascript. You can use AJAX to send this to a backend with something like php and then return xml.

usefull links:

[mootools request](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request) - for posting the form to the backend.
[php simpleXML](https://www.php.net/simplexml) - for making xml

Hope this will help.